# Cassandra DB Java: for each row gotten in query, fetch data stored in seperate table (eg counter table)?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-3.0

Does anyone know of an efficient way to fetch counter data stored in a separate table for each row gotten in a query?

The tables are defined as follows

```
TABLE person (
    id timeuuid,
    name text,
    many other attributes... );
TABLE person_counts(
      id timeuuid, //same id as person
      count1 counter,
      PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

The goal is that when persons/single person are fetched, before returning to add the count then return. Is iterating over each person and querying person_counts the only way to achieve this? It needs to be a counter however since I need a certain Primary Key for the person table I cannot have a counter directly there it seems.

I am using datastax cassandra if it makes a difference.

Comment: how often are reads vs updates?

Comment: Reads are relatively frequent and consistent, while updates  would likely be infrequent but happen in batches from a variety of sources.

Answer (score 0):

For this insertion, you can use the batch operation, which is an atomic operation in cassandra datastax driver. Whenever you try to enter a record in persons table, you have to create a prepared query for persons table and persons_count table, and add the two prepared queries to a single batch and carry on the insertion. The advantage with batches is, it is an atomic operation i.e., either it inserts both records or none at all.

In the same way whenever you want to delete from persons table, create a batch and delete from both the persons and persons_count table. You can read more about them here:https://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/basics/batches/

Note: The two tables are independent and you can read entries of the two tables separately.Inserting via batch operation does not make them interlinked.

Now, for the requirement of fetching, you have to first query the count from the table and then go to the persons table. Probably, there is no other way as cassandra doesn't support any joins. Moreover, you have to specify the primary key for the persons table and other attributes, which help in finalising whether count should be in other table or it can be use in the same table. If you are fine with this implementation, you can use this:

create table persons(id uuid,
name text, count counter, primary key(id, name));

and update statement for the counter column. Then, there is no need of other table too.